# Как передать один аргумент в метод вместо 3 определенных

Tags: javascript, typescript

Когда пытаюсь скомпилировать код, вижу такую ошибку: "Expected 3 arguments, but got 1" на мутод "refactorStudent" и "refactorInfo", подскажите как пофиксить. Да и вообще, правильно ли я использую TypeScript (только начал).

```js
//constructor for creating students 
class Student {

    constructor(public name: string, public surname: string, public age: number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }
    //rewrite one or all options of student info 
    public refactorStudent(name: string, surname: string, age: number): void {

        this.name = typeof name !== 'undefined' ? name : this.name;
        this.surname = typeof surname !== 'undefined' ? surname : this.surname;
        this.age = typeof age !== 'undefined' ? age : this.age;
    }
    //show info about student 
    public toString(): string {
        return `\nName: ${this.name}, Surname: ${this.surname}, Age: ${this.age}`;
    }
}
//constructor for create groups with students 
class Group {
    public students: any[];
    constructor(public nameGroup: string, public course: string, public specialization: string) {
        this.nameGroup = nameGroup;
        this.course = course;
        this.specialization = specialization;
        this.students = [];
    }
    //rewrite one or all options of group info 
    public refactorInfo(nameGroup: string, course: string, specialization: string): void {
        this.nameGroup = typeof nameGroup !== 'undefined' ? nameGroup : this.nameGroup;
        this.course = typeof course !== 'undefined' ? course : this.course;
        this.specialization = typeof specialization !== 'undefined' ?
            specialization : this.specialization;
    }
    //add new student
    public addStudent(...students: any[]) {
        this.students.push(...students);
    }
    // show info about group with students
    public toString(): string {
        return `Name of Group: ${this.nameGroup}; \nCourse: ${this.course}; \nSpecialization: 
${this.specialization};\nStudents: ${this.students}`
    }
}
// create students
let student1 = new Student("Aladin", "Indus", 20);
let student2 = new Student("Allah", "Babah", 25);
let student3 = new Student("Krishna", "harehare", 23);

// create group
let Devs = new Group("D-11", "4", "Front-end");
//rename group name
Devs.refactorInfo("D-12");
//push students into group
Devs.addStudent(student1, student2, student3);
//rename name of first student
student1.refactorStudent("Super");
console.log(Devs.toString());
```

Comment: Вроде можно добавить дефолтные значения переменных в функции, тогда по идее не будет ошибки - `name: string = '', ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если хочешь чтоб аргумент был не mandatory то добавь "?" как я написал ниже.

```
public refactorStudent(name?: string, surname?: string, age?: number): void {
    // ....
}
```